# Anyway to create a single bootable image from Windows Server Backup vhd files

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization

So I have a Window Server 2008 machine that I need to restore. The machine is on, but will not boot into the OS.

I really don't need the machine anymore.

I have Windows Server Backup vhd files.

Is there anyway to create a bootable image from the vhd files? I have other servers that can connect to the machine, run HyperV, run Windows Server Backup, but if the server will not boot to the operating system I think I am screwed.

I have tried creating a VM in HyperV but when I set any of the .vhd files to the VM IDE, the virtual machine will not boot.

If I could extract an image from the Windows Server Backup .vhds than I can create a VM and solve my problem. But I get the impression I cannot do this with Windows Server Backup .vhds

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, But based on my own experiences, this should work:
Here are the steps to follow:

> Create a virtual machine in Hyper-V and attach the Windows Server Backup VHD file
> Boot the Hyper-V machine to WinPE
>
> Launch Regedit
>
> Highlight HKLM and click Load Hive
>
> Depending on the configuration of the system partition, navigate to >C:\Windows\System32\config or D:\Windows\System32\config and load the SYSTEM hive
> Follow the registry changes listed below
>
> HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet001/Services/ and then then modify the "Start" value according to the numbers listed below:
>
> Aliide = 3
>
> Amdide =3
>
> Atapi = 0
>
> Cmdide = 3
>
> iaStorV = 3
>
> intelide = 0
>
> msahci = 3
>
> pciide = 3
>
> viaide = 3
>
> Highlight HKLM and click Unload Hive
> Reboot and wait a minute or two

(SOURCE: http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/IT/archive/2012/02/23/booting-a-windows-server-backup-vhd-in-hyper-v.aspx)

Comment: Do you know how I Boot the Hyper-V machine to WinPE? Not finding anything online that doesn't already assume you know what WinPE is and how to do it...

Comment: I don't think I can boot to WinPE unless the VM boots in the first place

Comment: You Might need a winPE disc from a good server image. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744530%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) try that

Comment: If you can't get PE set up easily, could you attach the VHD to an existing VM and edit the registry from that?